# Управление стилями в приложении Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-themes

В приложении объявлено несколько стилей: красная, зеленая и синяя темы. Присутствует код, который активирует одну из тем в ручном режиме.

Вопрос: как получить актуальную тему в Android Q? Скажем, нужно, чтобы в `Dark Mode` применялась синяя тема, а в `Light` - зеленая. Тогда как красная включается отдельно по требованию пользователя.

`AppCompatDelegate`, кажется, не совсем подходит. К тому же на Android M, к примеру, были проблемы с использованием этого класса, - приложение переставало отвечать.

Comment: не пойму, а что вам мешает использовать: getTheme()?

Comment: Таким образом можно получить сведения о выбранном стиле в системе?